# searchView onbackpressed problem with the view

Tags: android, searchview, onbackpressed

I have problem with back button of an activity that contains searchview  I'm focusing on searchview when the activity starts so the keyboard appears so that's okay with me so the problems is that I need 3 times to press it so I can back to another activity or .... the steps are:

1. first back button pressed the keyboard disappears that's fine with me and of course the focus gone
2. the search button disappears and autogenerates 3 dots on the right side of the toolbar without a job
3. back to the other activity or .....

I tried intent in backpressed method still I need to click 3 times to exit the activity
so what I want if is it possible to get back by pressing once or maximum twice not 3 times and why the 3 dots appears..?

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchbutton, menu);

    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search_text);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.requestFocus();
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            citiesAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try to override `onBackPressed` and finish the activity

Comment: I dont want to finish the application I want to get back to MainActivity
even if wanted to finish the app it takes 3 clicks to onBackPressed be active and that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

When the search view is focused and the keyboard opens, when you try to click on the device back button then the keyboard will hide first because it is the default behavior of SearchView.

Then, you can override `onBackPressed` and do those 2 actions in one go.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (!searchView.isIconified) {
            searchView.isIconified = true
            // TODO your code goes here after hiding the search view
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
            finish()
        }
    }
```